# Creating front end and connecting them in Java

Tags: java, swing, connection, frontend

I am a beginner in Java programming. Using JavaMail API, I wrote a program to send emails. Now I need to create a front end and connect those. I use only Notepad to write programs, I don't use any IDE.  How to create front end easily and connect to my program?

My program is:

```java
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.*;

public class Mailer {

    public void Mailer() throws Exception {
        String usrname;
        String pwd;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("\nEnter the gmail user name :");
        usrname = in.next();
        System.out.println("\nEnter the Password :");
        pwd = in.next();
        String HOST_NAME = "smtp.gmail.com";
        int HOST_PORT = 465;

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtps");
        props.put("mail.smtps.host", HOST_NAME);
        props.put("mail.smtps.auth", "true");

        Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
        Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport();

        String toadd;
        System.out.println("\nEnter the Recipient Address:");
        toadd = in.next();
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);

        System.out.println("\nEnter the Subject:");

        String sub = in.nextLine();
        message.setSubject(sub);

        System.out.println("\nEnter the message body:");
        String body = in.nextLine();
        message.setContent(body, "text/plain");
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(toadd));
        transport.connect(HOST_NAME, HOST_PORT, usrname, pwd);
        transport.sendMessage(message, message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
        transport.close();

        System.out.println("Mail Sent successfully!!!!");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("*******************Welcome to Mailer*************************");

        Mailer mail = new Mailer();
        mail.Mailer();
    }
}
```

Comment: The code as written is not written in such a way that the class can be used by a GUI, because it uses things like the `Scanner` and `System.out`.  To be usable by both a GUI and command line, the process of sending an email would need to be abstracted out to a class (or method) that is called by both.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If you don't use an IDE, your development will take a lot longer, and be much (much!) harder to debug and do right. I strongly suggest you take time to learn Eclipse or IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition: they're both free, not so difficult to use (if you don't use "advanced features"), and will save you a LOT of trouble down the road. Managing multiple classes with notepad is a nightmare, and I don't even talk about refactoring your code

Comment: For the GUI part: take look at the swing tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/

Answer (score 2):

1. Factor out a method which takes parameters and do the email sending.
   No system.out and system.in allowed in this method.
2. For a test, you can drive this method with your existing code parts
   which reads parameters from console.
3. Make a GUI form which contains all input fields and probably some
   button. Your code will start something like this: JFrame f = new
   JFrame(); f.add(new JLabel("to")); ... f.setVisible(true); You have
   to learn a lot about component layouts. This code can be in the 'main' method for simplicity.
4. Wire your frontend with the backend: create an actionListener method
   on the button which collects parameters from the input fields (getText()) and
   invokes the email sender method.

That's all. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make packages. Different Packages for different purposes.

Like you can create a package to get only your front end classes and other package containing your above class to send emails.

Then you can call methods of this class from your front end classes.

For making front end, you can use Swings to create GUI based front end or you can create CUI based front end too from Notepad.

It is not mandatory to use any IDE but that just makes easy to code.